# How to use common named_scope for all ActiveRecord models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Hi how to build a named_scope which will be common for all models.

Answer (score 9):

I do that by putting this code in `lib/has_common_named_scopes.rb`:

```
module HasCommonNamedScopes
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval {
      # Named scopes
      named_scope :newest, :order => "#{base.table_name}.created_at DESC"
      named_scope :freshest, :order => "#{base.table_name}.updated_at DESC"
      named_scope :limit, lambda { |limit| {:limit => limit} }
    }
  end
end
```

and then include the module in each model where I need them:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HasCommonNamedScopes
```

I'd recommend that you use `base.table_name` to qualify the table when referring to columns in these named scopes like I do in the example. Otherwise you run into problems with ambiguous references when you combine these named scopes with other scopes that join in other tables.

**Update:**

`scope` is used in Rails > 3 and `named_scope` was used in previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Thoughtbot's Pacecar](http://github.com/thoughtbot/pacecar), which adds a bunch of very common named scopes to every model. It might come with what you're looking for. If you need something custom, though, [Casper Fabricius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687236/how-to-use-common-namedscope-for-all-models/1687438#1687438) has the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

For a Rails4 project I achieved this by extending `ActiveRecord::Base`, the class all Rails models inherit from, in an initializer (monkey patching approach, beware)

```
# in /config/initializers/shared_scope_initializer.rb
module SharedScopes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def named_scope
      return where(attribute: value) # query here
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, SharedScopes)
```